# Eclipselink delete and create leads to unique constraint exception

Tags: eclipselink, entitymanager

I have an entity that has a custom set primary key. 
First I delete this entity and afterwards I recreate this entity with the same primary key. 
This leads to a unique constraint exception on commit/flush.
As a workaround I call a flush between the delete and create operation. 
Is there a way to do these things right/better, i.e. without calling the flush on the entitymanager?

Thanks,
Manfred

Answer (score 0):

`em.remove( yourEntity )` command will book your entity for removal from the Persistence Context and afterwards from the database, but it does not take effect immediatelly. I can imagine that removal from persistence context and database had not already happened when you persisted the new entity.

You may try to delete this entity with a custom JPQL query like `"DELETE FROM YourEntity ye WHERE ye.primary1 = :primary1 AND ye.primary2 = :primary2... whatever;"` after remove() command. I assume this removes your entity from the persistence context immediatelly, but I'm not sure. Give it a try, and let us know :)